# changing the DisplayMember of Syncfusion ComboBoxAutoComplete

Tags: winforms, syncfusion

I am working with Syncfusion tools, and am trying to add a `ComboBoxAutoComplete` control to a Windows form. I have a `DataTable` that I'm using as my `DataSource` with two columns: `ID` and `Name`. I set the `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, and `ValueMember` properties like so:

```
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteControl.DataSource = table
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

The control loads correctly, but it appears that the `DisplayMember` does not get applied. The control will display only the ID of the selected item. When I expand the drop-down, it displays the entire table (both columns). I tried setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` directly on the `AutoCompleteControl`, but those properties do not exist. Is there a different property that is used to control what text is displayed in the `ComboBoxAutoComplete` control?

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared the simple sample in which we have assigned data table to "DataSource" property of AutoCompleteControl inside the ComboBoxAutoComplete to enable the AutoComplete features.

To display the value based on DisplayMember assigned the Data table columns to “Columns” (collection property) of AutoCompleteControl and set “MatchingColumn” value as True for which column has been set in DisplayMember.

Please check with the sample from below location.

Sample: [ComboBoxAutoComplete_Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/181521/ze/ComboBoxAutoCompleteDisplayMember1573670164)

Regards,

Keerthana J

Comment: That helps with what is displayed in the ComboBox, but it does not affect what shows up in the dropdown. Is there a way to control what is displayed in the dropdown?